# How to retrieve automated test cases result using CAAC/Rally API

Tags: rally

I'm using this URL in REST:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcases?query=((Project.Name = "Team 2 - OCEANS Change Management") AND (Method = "Automated"))fetch=type,formattedId,Method,Owner

It is throwing this error:

```
{
  "QueryResult": {
    "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
    "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
    "Errors": [
      "Could not parse: Cannot parse expression \"((Project.Name = \"Team 2 - OCEANS Change Management\") AND (Method = \"Automated\"))fetch=type,formattedId,Method,Owner\" as a query"
    ],
    "Warnings": [],
    "TotalResultCount": 0,
    "StartIndex": 0,
    "PageSize": 0,
    "Results": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the string "fetch" should be "&fetch"?